# FIrebase Cloud Functions: Error while update multiple records at once

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

What I am trying to do : I am trying to update a separate node using cloud functions, whenever a new value is added to a particular node in the realtime database.

The code to update the realtime database:   (sometimes I update multiple nodes at once) using the {'uid/managedby' : 'newid'} notation.

```
  modifyManagerBeforeDelete(newManagedBy, oldManagedBy) {
    let updateVal = {};
    let ref = this.afDB.database.ref('users').orderByChild('managedby').equalTo(oldManagedBy);
    ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        let keys = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
        for (let uid of keys) {
          updateVal[uid + '/managedby'] = newManagedBy;
        }
        this.afDB.object('users').update(updateVal)
          .then(() => console.log("done"))
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      }
    });
  }
```

The cloud function:

```
exports.updatemanagedby = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/managedby').onUpdate(event => {
    if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
        var earlierHandler = event.data.previous.val();
        console.log("earlierHandler ", earlierHandler)
        var sourceId = event.params.uid;
        console.log("Current UID ", sourceId)
        console.log('/managedby/' + earlierHandler + '/' + sourceId);
        admin.database().ref('/managedby/' + earlierHandler + '/' + sourceId).once('value', function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.ref.remove()
        })
    }
    var newEmployee={}
    newEmployee[event.params.uid] = true;
    admin.database().ref('/managedby/' + event.data.val()).update(newEmployee)
        .then(()=>console.log("Update Successful"))
        .error((error)=>console.log(error));
})
```

Errors:

The realtime database is updated with no errors. However, with cloud functions I am getting two kinds of errors:

a) When I update one or two records in the realtime database and then cloud function onupdate is fired, I get:

> TypeError: admin.database(...)ref(...).update(...).then(...).error is
>   not a function

BUT the cloud function works and the records are updated.

b) When I update multiple nodes in the realtime database I get:

an infinite loop where the cloud function goes on and on and the app crashes. Cloud function does not make all the updates as is needed. How do I rectify this?